# Mysql_connect - access denied, но mysqli_connect - работает

Tags: mysqli, freebsd, mysql

Вечер добрый!

Я наверно уже тупею)

Подскажите, может кто сталкивался сбрал mysql'y не самую новую (5.1.72) собрал РНРпу.
Все ок, phpmyadmin ходит, и только одна херь, которую заказчики уже года три как сняли с поддержки пишет:

```
Access denied for user 'bitirx'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Тестовый скрипт показал, что пишет только у mysql_connect... mysqli_connect работает уже нормально...

Логин пароль-живые, mysqli авторизуется, myadmin входит, видит и работает с БД.

Хвост подсказывает, что где-то менялись механизмы авторизации)

Знает ли кто?

Спасибо!

---

Ответ. Спрашивающий тормозит... Ну или нефиг работать в воскресенье..

Была ошибка при обновлении портов... которая была пропущена.. ну и оно видать где-то с чем-то не состыковалась.
После обновления было пересобрано и запустилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

версия php какая? В 5.5 mysql уже в депрекейтиде, может из-за этого. Да и действительно давно пора перестать работать с mysql